# Google Fonts and web2py

Tags: css, fonts, web2py

I have this simple page:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito">
<style>
#font {
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  font-size: 48px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="font">Text here!</div>
</body>
</html>
```

It works pretty fine when I open the file in the browser, but when I put it online in static folder in web2py (on the PythonAnywhere), nothing changes, the font looks like simple Arial. So, what is wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you saying you are serving that entire HTML file as a static asset from web2py? What is the exact URL used to access the file?

Comment: I just uploaded the file in the "static" folder. The url is my_username.pythonanywhere.com/app_name/static/file.html

Comment: Is the URL http or https?

Comment: https and if I try to enter with http, the url always turns to https.

Comment: An interesting point: I just upload the same file on another server (orgfree) and everything seems okay, the page have the Nunito font.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing the CSS link to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito">
```

Removing the "http:" from the href will force the scheme to that of the parent page (in this case, "https").

Comment: since it's a css/link issue, also worked deploying Django at Python Anywhere